# Boardline case of $W^{2,p}$ estimates on elliptic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde

Suppose $u$ is a strong solution of
$$\begin{cases}\Delta u =f &\quad \text{in} \quad B_1(0)\\ u=0 &\quad \text{on}\quad \partial B_1\end{cases}$$
The well known $W^{2,p}$ estimates says if $f\in L^p(B_1)$, $1<p<\infty$, then $$||u||_{W^{2,p}(B_{\frac12})}\leq C||f||_{L^p(B_1)}$$
It is obtained through Calderon-Zygmund theory.

Does anyone know what will happen for $p=1$? What is the best we can say about $u$ and $\nabla u$? I saw a paper that says $\nabla u\in L^{2,\infty}$ (the weak $L^2$ space) through the knowledge of singular integral. I did not know how they get this. Can anyone give me more reference? Thank you.

Comment: I have no clue about these $L^{2,\infty}$ spaces or best results.  But I think a duality argument probably gives optimal $L^p$ estimates for $u$ and $ \nabla u$ (and is also a great example to apply this duality stuff)

Comment: also you can apply a duality argument to get results even if you weaken $L^1$ condition on $f$ to $ \int_{B_1} |f(x)| \delta(x) dx \le C$  where $\delta(x)$ is the distance to the boundary function.

Comment: You get  $\nabla u \in L^{N/(N-1), \infty}$.

Comment: Giorgio, where can I find such results? It would be great if you can give me more directions to search.

Comment: I know how to show $\nabla u\in L^{2,\infty}$. It just follows from Riesz potential argument. when $p=1$.

Comment: @Slm2004 Sorry for the late answer but I did not get any notification of your comment (you forgot @ before my name). The proof I know uses the heat semigroup and it is written in a paper by A. Lunardi and myself in some generality, but the result for the Laplacian is surely older. The title is "On domains of elliptic operators in $L^1$". If you don't find it, write an email to giorgio.metafune@unisalento.it

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your reference. That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Slm2004 Another proof came to mind and this should be the "standard" one. If $\Delta u =f \in L^1$, write $u$ as the newtonian potential of $f$ and differentiate under the integral. Then $\nabla u$ is estimated by the Riesz potential of $I_1(|f|)$  and it is well known that $I_1$ maps $L^1$ to weak $L^{N/(N-1)}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune  Yes. I also realize that.

Answer (score 2):

You may find useful a paper by Perez in Journal of Functional Analysis in 1995

Comment: Thank you for your answer